# Is there a way to avoid using app.get() for every static file in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm starting out with `express.js` and trying to serve lots of static files from the server (could be `.css`, `.jpg`, `.svg`, `.js` or other file types). Is there a way to do this without typing `app.get()` for each file? I know about `express.Router()` but then the clutter just goes over into another file.

Comment: Did you try searching for “expressjs serve static files” or similar? This is a solved problem with many, many examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use `express.static` middleware.

For example, use the following code to serve all the files from directory named public:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Now, you can load the files that are in the public directory:

```
http://localhost:3000/images/kitten.jpg
http://localhost:3000/css/style.css
http://localhost:3000/js/app.js
http://localhost:3000/images/bg.png
http://localhost:3000/hello.html
```

More info here: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html